# How to avoid already selected value from the facets(list) - VisualSearch

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, facet

In rails 4.0.2, I am using VisualSearch.js for search's front end section. The issue is, user can select same value more than one time.

Using this plugin, how can I avoid already selected value from the facet's list. 
At least selected value should be in disable format. How can I achieve this?

Reference Link: http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/

Answer (score 2):

Use this following code to get rid of this.

1. Declare your facets first.

   var facets = [
                     'Pcode',
                     'Pack Type',
                     'Pack Size',
                     'Printing Type',
                   ];

   2. Get your selected facets.

   var currentFacets = visualSearch.searchQuery.pluck("category");

   3. Remove already selected facets using this.

   facets = facets.filter(function (el) {return currentFacets.indexOf(el) < 0;});

   4. Finally pass the unselected facets to the callback function.

      callback(facets);

**Complete Code**

```
facetMatches: function (callback) {
                var facets = [
                  'Pcode',
                  'Pack Type',
                  'Pack Size',
                  'Printing Type',
                ];

                var currentFacets = visualSearch.searchQuery.pluck("category");

                facets = facets.filter(function (el) {
                    return currentFacets.indexOf(el) < 0;
                });



                callback(facets);
            }
```

Thanks,
Bharathi Subramanian.